# Executing a linux program from php

Tags: php, linux, shell, centos

Using the following software: http://silvercoders.com/en/products/doctotext/

I got it to work on my Window's machine using this following code:

```
<?php    

$file = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\SMF\sdsdssss.docx';

$content = exec( 'C:\xampp\htdocs\SMF\doctotext\doctotext.exe /c '. $file , $output );

var_dump( $output );
```

However, when I tried it on my Centos machine, using the linux x86_64 version of the software, I cannot get it to work. (Yes, my machine is x86_64 too)

I tried:

```
<?php

$file = '/home/***/public_html/downloads/test_doc.docx';

$content = shell_exec( '/home/***/public_html/doctotext/doctotext.sh \c '. $file , $output );
```

But nothing outputs. What is the equivalent execution format for those running centos.

Please advise

Comment: Have you checked so you have php installed on the linux box? You can do this by running `php -v` from the terminal.

Comment: I found out yesterday that the doctotext for windows is different than the linux version. When you run .exe on windows, it incorportates all the subsidiary files, but that's not the case with the linux package. Hence, I need to know how to actually install the damn program because when I tried running it through command line, it kept telling me files were missing. My question now is: how do I install this on my Linux machine, which when done properly, all the files required to run it are included: https://github.com/karlproject/doctotext

Comment: Then you should start a new question since the context is completly different.

Answer (score 0):

First of all [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) does not take a second argument. I think you are confusing the function with [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) which does take more than one argument:

```
exec('/home/***/public_html/doctotext/doctotext.sh \c '. $file, $output, $return);
```

From the documentation for `shell_exec()`:

> This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required.

Second, I think you first should check so the shell script has execute permissions. You can set the correct permissions using:

```
chmod +x /home/***/public_html/doctotext/doctotext.sh
```

Depending on what the script is doing you might also need to run it with root privileges:

```
sudo php -f myscript.php
```

If you are running the script through your browser you should also make sure so that the path to the shell script is readable by the webserver.

It would also be nice if you enabled error reporting and check if you get any error messages when running your script.

Comment: I tried the following and still get no output:

    $content =  exec('/home/***/public_html/doctotext/doctotext.sh \c '. $file, $output, $return);

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting in your php file? Have you dump out the variables `$content`, `$output` and `$return`? Have you verified so the file really exists in the specified location and so that is have the correct permissions?

Comment: Here's what I did:

var_dump( $content ): I GOT string(0) "" 
var_dump( $output ): I GOT array(0) { } 
var_dump( $return ): I GOT int(126) 
var_dump( $string ): I GOT string(0) ""

Comment: Apologies: The file exists and the permission has been set to 777; additionally, the script that contains the code also is at 777. I have root access to the server as it is a dedicated server. Will pay top dollar to get this to work. Please advice :(

Comment: @stylusss - How are you running your php file, from the terminal or from the browser? If you are using the later please try to run the file from the terminal using `sudo php -f <script.php>` and see if that works. Also like I said before enable error reporting by putting `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script. The reason why you would want to run the script from the commandline is because if you run it through the browser the webserver and not you will execute the script.

Comment: @stylusss - Also, you got a return code of `126` which states that this is a permission problem or that the command could not be executed.

Comment: @stylusss - You should also make sure so that the path is readable by the webserver. If you can execute the command from the terminal using `php -f <script.php>` but not from the browser the path is **not** readable by webserver.

Comment: When I run `sudo php -f /home/***/public_html/test.php` in root, it displays everything inside that file, as if it were actually displayed in a browser (i.e. it's source). Placing `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` displays errors, but not pertaining to this code, as I added an undefined variable just to make sure it would display an error. I recursively gave all files within /doctotext/ `777` permission too, just in case. Unfortunately, still not displaying text found inside the file. It's unfortunate b/c on my window's machine it works. Have you tried it on your linux machine?

Comment: @stylusss - I can help you in chat instead - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139141/executing-a-linux-program-from-php

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the credentials to be there, need 20 points of some sort.

Comment: @stylusss - You could start by upvoting my answer since I spent alot of time trying to help you =)

Comment: Absolutely, I will